# Rails forms, change field name dynamically with iteration variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I have an iteration for all my locales.

I want the `:text` and `:title` field on every iteration to change depending on the locale, for example, `:title_en` for English, `:title_ru` for Russian, `:title_gr` for Greek and so on.

The `en`, `ru`, `gr` and so on are the `locale` in my iteration so I get them from there.

```
<% I18n.available_locales.map.with_index(1) do |locale, index| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title_(I want to use the locale here) %>
<% end %>
```

How do I go about that? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You just want to change the symbol :tilte_LOCALE depending on the variable locale?

Comment: @BramVandenbogaerde yes exactly, seems pretty simple but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `form` builder support all locales, you can try this:

```
<% I18n.available_locales.each.with_index(1) do |locale, index| %>
   <%= f.text_field "title_#{locale}".to_sym %>
<%end%>
```

And to show the **title_(locale)** of each **Post** (or whatever class you got) :

```
<% Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).each do |post| %>
  <% I18n.available_locales.map.with_index(1) do |locale, index| %>
    <%= post.send("title_#{locale}") %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you but may I ask you one more thing. I am trying to show the content of `article.title_(locale)` now, and `article."title_#{locale}".to_sym` does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I actually found it, let me edit the answer for future viewers.

Comment: @dyserone show me the  full code which you try to use, exactly `article.title_(loca‌​le)`.

Comment: I found the solution and edited the answer, but if you still want to see it I can post it.

Comment: you can omit `to_sym` here.